# Elasticsearch query in Julia

Tags: elasticsearch, julia

How do I connect Julia with Elasticsearch? Has anyone ever tried it, or found a package that is ready to use?

I know that in Julia we can use python package, but I still have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There it is:

```
#Installation
using Conda
Conda.add("elasticsearch")

# loading module and getting connection
using PyCall
elasticsearch = pyimport("elasticsearch")
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch() # <== this is the connection to ES
es.info()  # connection information

# put some data
dat = Dict("a1"=>"blaaa", "a2"=>"hello")
res = es.index(index="data", doc_type="data", id="1", body=dat)

# fetch some data
q1 = Dict("query"=>Dict("match"=>Dict("a1"=>Dict("query"=>"blaaa"))))
es.search("data",body=q1)["hits"]["hits"]
```